# Unity - Vertex light ignored by static objects (lightmapped)

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapping, shader, vertex, light

Vertex lights work fine on dynamic objects, but the second I make them static and bake lightmaps they're ignored.

I've tried changing to different "lightmodes" within the shader, but none has worked. Lightmode "ForwardBase" seems to really mess up, even though I would assume its the one to use given its description on https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-PassTags.html

Any suggestions would be very appreciated :)

Comment: So by the sound if it this only occurs with a specific shader you're working on getting to work right, is this correct?

Comment: It is a custom shader, but this seems to be the case with all the builtin shaders as well (including the standard shader). If you make a object static and bake lightmaps only the pixel lights will work, and they're simply too performance hungry for my use case.

Comment: Sounds like some setting is set up wrongly in your project. Try make a new project and test out if you can bake a light map succesfully there.

Comment: This happens on fresh projects as well. Baking lightmaps isnt the problem, they bake just fine. The issue is using vertex lights (not pixel lights) with lightmapped meshes. Using vertex lights (E.g by setting lights rendermode to "not important") works fine with dynamic objects that don't use lightmaps. But the second objects are set to static and maps baked, only pixel lights will interact with surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My understanding of the question at hand**

As I understand, when you bake a lightmap, the only light source that will change the light of the baked objects is a pixel light. But you would like to make it work with a vertex light.

I'm still not entirely sure whether you mean that the light simply won't bake into the baked map in the first place, or whether it cannot affect the light level of the object after it has been baked.

In any case, I did some searching.

**Possible solution/explanation 1**

When I searched I came across this tool and description.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/vertex-lit-shader-baked-shadows-realtime-light-75977

> By default, using Unity’s built-in shader Mobile/VertexLit lighting
>   works only as either baked or realtime but you cannot display a
>   realtime light on a baked surface. This shader allows a baked surface
>   to also receive realtime lighting.

Note that the tool is free.

---

**Possible solution/explanation 2**

I also came across this tutorial: https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/rendering/part-16/

Where the author writes

> When lightmaps are used, Unity will never include vertex lights. Their
>   keywords are mutually exclusive. So we don't need a variant with both
>   VERTEXLIGHT_ON and LIGHTMAP_ON at the same time.

Lastly please note that these solutions seem to be developed at earlier versions of Unity. Newer solutions more appropriate may exist.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: First thanks for the response(s). Yes the baked lights work just fine, and they're not suppose to be mixed. The issue is purely with the realtime lights who should affect static models (but not bake ofcause). The article on "catlikecoding" was the one that lead me to believe this would be an issue stating "When lightmaps are used, Unity will never include vertex lights", which is what I want. I did not notice the shader on the asset store, and it seems to work from what I've tested. A user on the unity forums noted that I needed to write a custom lighting function. Thanks for the help man.